# Backed up... road

Tags: grammar

The traffic is backed up,  but, aside from saying this,  can we say the road is backed up instead? If not,  why?  Thanks for helping.

Comment: Yes, but you'd better be more specific about the context. If you're on the road, it's the traffic that's backed up; the road is just the same. If you're elsewhere, you can talk about the road being backed up: _Northbound I-5 is backed up for 3 miles at Mount Vernon._

Comment: Don't you mean 'If so, why?'? It's the traffic that's backed up. The rest is transference of meaning.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was once on a flight when the Captain said, before take off "In a couple of minutes, we shall be lining up the runway". I think we all knew what he meant, but I was glad his aeronautical skills exceeded his precision in the use of English - and yes, he was an Englishman!

Comment: I understand, so it's correct but put more details,  right?

Comment: @john lawler, please excuse my ignorance, could you tell me the mistake in the pilot's remark? Thanks

Comment: Oh no I mean WS2, im sorry im new at this

Comment: Certainly if you listen to "traffic reports" on the radio in any large US city you will hear statements such as "Route 27 is backed up from the river bridge to Interstate 15".  It's unjustifiable pedantry to insist that something like "the traffic on ..." be inserted into that perfectly clear and concise statement to satisfy some theoretical orthodoxy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Usually we would say "the road is backed up *with traffic*".

It's easy to find examples by Googling **"road is backed up"**

e.g.

> The Anthony Henday at Lessard Road is backed up with cars and tow trucks in Edmonton
>
> [Edmonton Journal](http://www.edmontonjournal.com/Anthony+Henday+Lessard+Road+backed+with+cars+trucks+Edmonton+2014/10422829/story.html)

Comment: Thanks especially for the example.  I actually tried googling but didn't find any

Comment: Did you include the quotation marks?

Answer (score 0):

"To back up" and the noun "backup" referring to traffic jam seems to be American English.